# What can I do with an IP address of a visitor that tried to access a shell exploit that was planted on my system?

Tags: ip, hacking

My website was exploited (don't worry about how) and the result was there were several WebShells installed in various locations. [The exact web shell is just like the one listed in this question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328235/how-does-this-giant-regex-work).

I deleted the shell file, obviously, and did my best to resolve the exploit. In the meantime, I caught an IP address in my site's error logs trying to access said shell file. The IP is coming out of Waterloo, Ontario from a Rogers Cable IP address. This appears to be a residential IP.

So, besides blocking the IP, is there anything else I can do with this? Report it to Rogers - would they believe me, would they bother? Is it possible that it's just a zombie computer proxying the request for the real attacker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell your ISP and/or hoster, and you can tell their ISP. That's about it. No one else will care. They might not care. It is very likely that the machine's a zombie.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're a large company or a government entity, your chances of getting anywhere are slim to none. Report it to the abuse contact for the IP block and perhaps your local police.